# How to left align p:datatable filter text box?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

```
<p:column style="text-align: left;width:60px;"
          headerText="Zone"
          filterBy="#{shopsCentroidMP.centroidMZone}"
          filterMatchMode="contains"
          filterStyle="width:70% !important;"
          sortBy="#{shopsCentroidMP.centroidMZone}"/>
```

Note : `filterStyle` should be left aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add below code to your datatable CSS . Filter Text box will leftAligned .

```
.ui-datatable  .ui-column-filter {
margin-left: -2px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align the text inside the filter text box, you can add this rule to your css:

```
.ui-column-filter {
    text-align: left !important;
 }
```

If you want to align only the components inside the customFilterColumn:

```
.ui-column-customfilter {
   text-align: left !important;
}
```

Comment: i want to align the Text box same same column header (both left align) , Not filter Text .